# Inheritance and the "this" keyword

Tags: java, inheritance, this

Suppose that we have next situation:

Parent class A:

```
class A{  
    public A(){}
    public doSomething(){  
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
    }
}
```

with a child class B:

```
class B extends A{  
    public B(){}
    public void doSomething(){
        super.doSomething();
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
    }
}
```

and Main class:

```
class Main{  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A ab=new B();
        ab.doSomething();
    }
}
```

When I execute this code result is

```
B  
B
```

Why does `this`, referenced in superclass A, returns `B` as a class when the *reference* is of type A?

Comment: Why nobody answered the solution too? that will be great for beginner like me.

Answer (score 21):

It doesn't matter what the reference is, it's the instantiated object's class that counts.  The object that you're creating is of type B, therefore this.getClass() is always going to return B.

Comment: So, if i understand well, this is all about concept of polymorphism or, in other words, it is all about possibility that reference of abstract type(in my case reference this of type A) holds concrete object(in my case object of type B) .  
So, when i call some method in runtime on abstract reference(in my case A), which is overriden in some concrete type(in my case B) JAVA executes method of concrete type and, besause of that, this.getClass() in A class have same point as next line...  


`A ab=new B(); ab.getClass(); //result is call to getClass method of B object in runtime`

Comment: Yes, it will always call the overridden method, unless you use the super keyword.  That said, the getClass method isn't being overridden in your example, getClass just returns the runtime class of an object, ie the concrete, instantiated type of the object.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the fact that you are calling the `doSomething()` method of `A`, the `this` during that call is a `B`, and so the `getClass()` method is called on `B` not on `A`.  Basically the `this` will always be a `B` whether you are using a method from superclass `A`, a method from `B`, or from `A`'s superclass `Object` (the parent class of all Java classes).

Comment: @slomir - thanks for pointing that out - I guess `getClass()` still uses the runtime type no matter what.  Ammended my answer.

Comment: Hm... Maybe i'm wrong in something but i try to put System.out.println(super.getClass()) in B and it prints B, not A :(

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment to emphasize the confusion, but ok, you clarify ... getClass always return runtime type... Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

`this` doesn't do anything for you in this situtaion.  Calling `this.getClass()` is no different than just calling `getClass();`

So, A calls getClass(), which will return B if you are dealing with an instance of B that extends A.

Comment: Better say it the other way around: `getClass()` is a shortcut to `this.getClass()`.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it in terms of runtime vs static types:

```
Animal a = new Cat();
```

The static type (in this case written on the left hand side) of variable `a` is `Animal` (you couldn't pass a into a method that required a `Cat` without a downcast) but the runtime type of the object pointed to by `a` is `Cat`.

`a.getClass()` exposes the runtime type (if it helps think of it as the most specific subtype).

Interestingly in Java overloaded methods are resolved at compile-time (without looking at the runtime type).  So given then following two methods:

```
foo(Cat c);
foo(Animal animal)
```

Calling `foo(a)` would call the latter.  To 'fix' this the visitor pattern can be used to dispatch based on the runtime type (double dispatch).

Comment: Instead of "runtime type of ...", you could better say "the class of ..." (since it always is a class). So, it is simply a difference between type of variables and expressions versus class of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The output of program is correct.

When in Main class ab.doSomething(); line get executed doSomething() method of class B will be called then super.doSomething(); line will call doSomething() method of class A. As this keyword indicates reference of current object(ab is the object of class B see  A ab=new B(); as constructor is of class B),i.e.System.out.println(this.getClass()); line in class A will print B only.

Again control will come back to  System.out.println(this.getClass());in class B, So again B will get print.

In birdeye view only object of class B has created. That is why we are getting B B in output.