# Subclass calling a superclass method using "this"

Tags: java, inheritance, this, extends, superclass

If superclass has a method that uses the keyword "`this`" and subclass call this method, would superclass method using "`this`" refer to the subclass object?

Comment: No, the inheritance is only child to parent, parent won't be able to access child methods

Comment: This always refers to current object whether it is of parent or child class. If subclass calls the method of parent class then `this` will refer to child class object. But you cannot call the object of child class in parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance and the "this" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155811/inheritance-and-the-this-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

No , `this` will always referes to the instance of the class in which we are using it.

> If we use `this` in parent class it will always return parent class
>   instance.

If you want to use `this` of child class in parent class method,Please override the method of parent class.

Answer (score 0):

`this` always refer to the self object. ie., If a child uses `this` reference, it points to child. If a parent uses `this`, it points to  parent.

If `this` cannot find a reference to what is needed in the self, then it looks for the reference in parent.

I doubt your confusion is coming from method overriding, where a parent may call a method with `this` , but method in child is executed. This is because, the object which gets created in always of the child. So `this` points to child in that case.

Put it simply, `this` points to the instance of class which was instantiated. If that instance does not contain the referred entity, then lookup is done on parent (if any)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `this` in a class will always refer to the object.

I have crated few sample classes for better understanding.

#### Parent Class

```
public class TestClass{
    public void func(){
        this.cFunc();
        System.out.println("In Parent");
    }

    public void cFunc(){
        System.out.println("cFunc in parent");
    }
}
```

#### Child Class

```
public class TestClassChild extends TestClass{
    public void cFunc(){
        System.out.println("cFunc in child");
    }
}
```

### Cases

#### 1) Child Object accessed using Child Class reference

```
TestClassChild tc = new TestClassChild();
tc.func();
```

Output

```
cFunc in child - Child method is called
In Parent
```

#### 2) Child Object accessed using Parent Class reference

```
TestClass t = new TestClassChild();
t.func();
```

Output

```
cFunc in child - Irrespective if it was referenced by parent still child method got called. 
In Parent
```

#### 3) Parent Object accessed using Parent Class reference

```
TestClass tp = new TestClass();
tp.func();
```

Output

```
cFunc in parent - Parent function got called.  
In Parent
```

Hope the below examples will make things clear for you.